# Copy columns between sheets, if they do not yet exist

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way or method to copy (adding new) columns between sheets.

Let me illustrate:

**Sheet: template**

[image]

**Sheet: student**

[image]

Initially I duplicate "Template" and rename it.
But when additional tasks are added to "Template" I want to update "Student" minding that I have already changed the content in range B2:D4. So copy/pasting the whole range is not an option.

What's the best way to go about this?
First checking if row A in the destination sheet has a value, if not copy/paste that column?

A push in the right direction (or some code to get started on) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, I think best approach would be VBA code to detect what `Task` columns are the new ones and copy those into `Student`. Probably you'll need to loop trough each column anc check if the Header (Task 1, Task 2, and so on) exist or not in Student. IF not, copy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by looping true columns headers, given they are in the first row and all tabs are named appropriately:

```
Sub AddTask()

With Application

.ScreenUpdating = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
.AskToUpdateLinks = False
.DisplayStatusBar = True

End With

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

With wb
Dim LastTemplateCol As Long: LastTemplateCol = .Worksheets("Template").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For i = 2 To LastTemplateCol

    Dim TempTask As String: TempTask = .Worksheets("Template").Cells(1, i).Value
    Dim LastStudentCol As Long: LastStudentCol = .Worksheets("Student").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For t = 2 To LastStudentCol
    
    Dim StudTask As String: StudTask = .Worksheets("Student").Cells(1, t).Value
    Dim Exists As Boolean: Exists = False
    
    If TempTask = StudTask Then
    Exists = True
    GoTo taskloop:
    Else
    GoTo studloop:
    End If
    
studloop:
    Next t

If Exists = False Then

.Worksheets("Template").Cells(1, i).Columns.EntireColumn.Copy
.Worksheets("Student").Cells(1, LastStudentCol + 1).PasteSpecial
End If

taskloop:
Next i

End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```